# Nested jQuery IF statements not working

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_332258_327" value="Standard" class="member-type" />
<input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_332258_327" value="Youth" class="member-type" />
<input type="radio" name="CAT_Custom_332258_327" value="Family Add-On" class="member-type" />

<input type="radio" name="highflight" value="print" class="highflight-type" />
<input type="radio" name="highflight" value="digital" class="highflight-type" />
<input type="radio" name="highflight" value="printdigital" class="highflight-type" />
```

I have 2 sets of radio buttons and an "Amount" text field (#Amount). When I change the selection in the second radio button set (.highflight-type), it should update the Amount text field based on the values of both radio button sets.

```
$(".highflight-type").click(function(){

                if($(this).val()=="print") {
                    if($('.member-type').val()=="Standard") {
                        $('#Amount').val('35');
                    }
                    if($('.member-type').val()=="Youth") {
                        $('#Amount').val('35');
                    }
                }

                if($(this).val()=="digital") {
                    if($('.member-type').val()=="Youth") {
                        $('#Amount').val('10');
                    }
                    if($('.member-type').val()=="Standard") {
                        $('#Amount').val('25');
                    }
                }
                if($(this).val()=="printdigital") {
                    if($('.member-type').val()=="Standard") {
                        $('#Amount').val('50');
                    }
                    if($('.member-type').val()=="Youth") {
                        $('#Amount').val('35');
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, when I have "Youth" selected in the first radio button set (.member-type) and change the second radio button to "digital", I get an #Amount value of $25 instead of $10. I've used an alert to confirm the .member-type value in the DOM at the time I change the .highflight-type radio button selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just change

```
if($('.member-type').val()=="...")
```

to

```
if($('.member-type:checked').val()=="...")
```

Then the problem will be solved.

[**DEMO**.](http://jsfiddle.net/3J3tn/)

Comment: I suspect all answers submitted so far are valid, but I like the simplicity of this one -- and it does seem to work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`$('.member-type').val()` will always return the `value` of the first `.member-type` radio button.

Instead, you should filter the radio buttons to find the one that is checked, and get *that* radio button's value:

```
var $types = $('.member-type');
var $amount = $('#Amount');
var pricing = {
    print: {
        Standard: 35,
        Youth: 35
    },
    digital: {
        Standard: 25,
        Youth: 10
    },
    printdigital: {
        Standard: 50,
        Youth: 30
    }
};

$(".highflight-type").change(function() {

    if ( ! this.checked ) return;

    $amount.val(
        pricing[ this.value ][ $types.filter(':checked').val() ]
    );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C8kZq/

Comment: This is very educational. Interestingly, I've been using my targeting technique for over a year and a half without issues. It wasn't until I tried to add these nested IFs that it started giving me grief. Regardless, I see what you're explaining here and it's great for future reference. For now, I'm going to try to roll with Heera's solution because it's such a simple change. Thanks-